# The relation between managedObject class and my own model classes?

Tags: ios, core-data

In this [article](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-overview.html), it says "Core Data is a model layer technology. Core Data helps you build the model layer that represents the state of your app. "

I'm confused about the relation between managedObject class and my own model classes. If I use core data, should I use managedObject classes instead of my own model classes through all over the project, which means parsing the download JSON data to managedObject instances, configure view appearance with managedObject instances?

If not, should I convert instances of my model classes to managedObject instances only for persistence?

Answer (score 2):

Yes u need to use NSManagedObject class instead of your own NSObject class for persistance behaviour as the name of the NSManagedObject class is same as your Entity name and the objects name are same given in the entities objects.

Answer (score 0):

NSManagedObject is a generic class that implements all the basic behavior required of a Core Data model object. It is not possible to use instances of direct subclasses of NSObject (or any other class not inheriting from NSManagedObject) with a managed object context.

Answer (score 0):

If you need persistence in your app then you can use Core Data NSManagedObject for your data classes or build persistence layer yourself (using FMDB or other libraries).

If you decide on using Core Data, you can subclass NSManagedObject class and create your model base class which all your models are based on. This is a good way to add often used functionality that all model classes can use. E.g. there are some class methods I add to my NSManagedObject subclassed base class:

```
@interface MyManagedObject : NSManagedObject

/// Returns string representation of entity name (i.e class name)
+ (NSString*) entityName;

/// Returns new instance of entity in passed context
+ (instancetype) newInstanceInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)pContext;

/// Returns fetch request for the entity
+ (NSFetchRequest *) fetchRequest;

@end
```